# Windows machine does not sync it's folders

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows-7

Natty uploads files instantly, but the Win7 box does not sync it's folders, it does not down or up-load anything. Ubuntu ONE client in Windows says "Recync up-to-date", but it just is not.

No problems with Natty Narwhal though.

Comment: It appears, that if I add files to the folders I want to synch, they will upload! But the old files in the folders do not!

Comment: I changed a file in my Ubuntu, and I disappeared alltogether from my Windows machine (the original source of it!).

Comment: Uninstalled Ubuntu ONE from Windows. Case closed.

Comment: We could have solved your problem if you had reported a bug in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client, but it seems you where in a rush..

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, on my desktop and laptop I have Ubuntu 11.10 and it syncs perfectly between the two.

When I installed Ubuntu One on my Notebook running Windows 7, it started to sync but after 20 seconds or so it stopped, nothing synced and clicking on sync did not appear to work.

So I left it switched on and started searching the forums, didn't get much help but when I looked at Ubuntu One for Windows on the notebook (which I had previously left switched on) it was syncing and synced fine.

All I need to check now is to see if it will update the server each time I make a change on a file in the same way as the 2 Ubuntu machines do on the fly

UPDATE:

It worked fine, all my files have synced between all 3 machines.

Works quicker//better in Ubuntu but no problems in Windows 7, just a little slower to sync